# Google Drive REST API (Server to Server): no binding with account files

Tags: google-drive-api

I try getting list of Google Drive files from my application (simple Google account)(https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

1. List with OAuth2 authorization work perfect: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it
2. I've create service account with delegation to Google Apps domain (https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts):
   [image] and download json service key.
3. Apply to GD from application:

   ```
   private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
   private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();


   static {
     try {
       HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
     } catch (Throwable t) {
       t.printStackTrace();
       System.exit(1);
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Credential credential = GoogleCredential
           .fromStream(new FileInputStream(".\\config\\google_drive_api.json"))
           .createScoped(DriveScopes.all());

     Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("javawebinar-1314").build();

     FileList result = service.files().list().execute();
     List<File> files = result.getFiles();
     System.out.println(files.size());
   ```

API work: result at the beginning was single "Getting started" file, now result is 0. It seems that service account has no any relation to my own and delegating to doman has no meening for me as I have no domain account.

Are there any possibility to manage my simple google account google drive files by REST API ?

Comment: I don't exactly get what you mean manage your simple Google account aside from getting list of Google Drive files from your application which you mentioned that it already worked perfectly. But, have you went through [Google Drive REST API Overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk#create_and_open_files_directly_from_the_drive_ui)?

Comment: Yes, I've gone.
I need to get list of Google Drive files from my application.
It work with https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it but return 0 files for service account